# PCRE regex capture group can be numbers or letters but can't be just numbers

Tags: regex

I have seen a host of questions very similar to this but they're not able to quite collect what I'm looking for.

I have a search system for finding PDO named placeholders in an SQL string.

PDO placeholders can be `A-z`, `0-9`, or `_` and always begin with `:`. However, in some circumstances date and time values also appear which naturally use `:` (`12:35`).

I need to check to find placeholders that match the PDO criteria but which are *not just* numeric.

Can  I do this in a single Regex?

The regex I have developed at the moment is:

```
/:(?:[A-Z_]*)(?=[0-9]*)/gmi
```

But this cuts off when any digit is found, see the below example SQL:

```
SELECT name, horse, id, DATE_FORMAT(Nee.datetimed, '12:12:12 @ %D') as del_time 
     FROM members WHERE biztype LIKE CONCAT('%',:bizb,'%') 
     AND (locate LIKE '%hos%' OR locate LIKE '%all%') 
     AND bizcat LIKE CONCAT('%',:catb7,'%') ORDER BY `status` DESC, RAND()
```

I need to catch `:catb7` and `:bizb` but ignore the time values.

My Regex above catches `:bizb` and `catb` but that catch is incorrect as it chops off the 7.

> ```
>  /:(?:[A-Z_]*(?:[0-9]*))/gmi
> ```

Catches `:12` and `:12` which is incorrect.

> ```
>  /:(?:[A-Z_]*)(?=[0-9]*)/gmi
> ```

Catches `:` as well which is incorrect.

Various tweaks and changes to the capture groups can't seem to find the correct result: Looking for:

```
:<any letter or number or underscore, any length, must contain at least one letter or underscore>
```

- 

> Valid catches:
>
> ```
>   :adbcd
>   :5fedg
>   :56_gt
>   :der
>   :9_6
> ```
>
> INVALID catches:
>
> ```
>  :12 
>  :1
>  :%D [MySQL date formatting]
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```php
\B:(?!\d+\b)\w+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rbLpRX/1).

*Details*:

- `\B` - a non-word boundary position (start of string or a non-word char must appear immediately to the left of the current location)
- `:` - a colon
- `(?!\d+\b)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there are one or more digits followed with a word boundary immediately to the right of the current location
- `\w+` - one or more word chars (letters/digit/underscores)

Comment: hmmm, what is the requirement for the `\B`? It seems to work just as well without the `\B`, am I missing something?

Comment: @Martin I explained the meaning of `\B`. Note that it will make sure the match starts only after a non-word char or start of string. This is in line with the requirment not to match in strings like `23:34:45`. However, the lookahead already does this check for digits, so it is probably redundant in the end. It is not redundant if you do not want to get a `:abc` match in a `def:abc` string. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/rbLpRX/2) vs. [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/rbLpRX/3).

Comment: Yes my test SQL string hadn't looked at `abd:def` things. I don't think they're valid for  PDO named placeholders so good to disqualify them too. Thanks again `:-)`